# UIViewController dismiss issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, runloop

I want to wait until dismiss animation completes but I don't want to use many blocks in my code, so I wrote this function in `UIViewController` `extension` (almost like this worked several years ago for me):

```
func dismissAnimated() {
   var comleted: Bool = false
   self.dismiss(animated: true) {
      comleted = true
   }

   while !comleted {
      RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoop.Mode.common, before: Date.distantFuture)
   }
}
```

so now instead of:

```
viewController.dismiss(animated: true) {
    // code after completion
}
```

I was supposed to write:

```
viewController.dismissAnimated()
// code after completion
```

But it doesn't dismiss view controller and doesn't enter into completion block.

I tried different RunLoop modes, tried different dates, tried inserting RunLoop.current.run into while condition, it didn't work. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

**Edit:**

And it worked on iOS 9 or something like this (may be with some code changes, because I can't find my source code). I start `RunLoop.current.run` to avoid blocking main thread. For instance, if I put `completed = true` in DispatchQue.main.asyncAfter , it will work, the issue is with `dismiss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again because I was curious and this solution actually works for me:

```
@objc private func dismissTapped() {

    let dismissalTime = dismissAnimated()
    print("Dismissal took: %ld", abs(dismissalTime))

}

private func dismissAnimated() -> TimeInterval {

    let startDate = Date()

    var completed = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        completed = true
    }

    while !completed {
        RunLoop.current.run(mode: .default, before: .distantFuture)
    }

    return startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow

}
```

iOS 12.1.2 | Swift 4.2

Comment: Thank you, it works, actually it works only when I tap, if I call dismissAnimated() from DispatchQueue.main, it doesn't work (dismiss works but completion never called), but I'll try to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't dismiss because your `while !completed` loop has stalled the main thread and the UI update happens on the main thread. What is wrong with running whatever code you need to run inside the `dismiss` completion closure?

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    runSomeCode()
}
```

Comment: because of improving archichecture decision I'd better use code without block, anyway the question is how to make this decision to work. And it worked on iOS 9 or something like this (may be with some code changes, because I can't find my source code). I run runLoop to avoid blocking main thread. For instance, if I put in DispatchQue.main.asyncAfter , it will work, the issue is with dismiss

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just about not using blocks maybe this may be a solution?

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    if self.navigationController?.isBeingDismissed ?? self.isBeingDismissed  {
        print("Dismissal completed...")
    }
}
```

Comment: No I need to accomplish the task using RunLoop because the code almost like this worked before

Comment: Actually found a solution that works. See new Answer.